# Gdb search core dump memory

Tags: gdb, coredump

I am new to gdb and I am trying to figure out if there is a way to do this:
I have a reference and want to know where all this reference is been used in a core dump heap memory, something like a search for all occurrences of this reference in heap memory. Sorry if this question makes no sense or seems too simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So first you need to find out where the memory has been mapped. This can be done with either "**info files**" or "**maintenance info sections**". After you have the mappings you can use the gdb find command on each of these mappings. The gdb find command has the following syntax:

```
find begin-address end-address address-to-search-for
```

Comment: is there anyway to automate this to scan all areas of memory?